# Convert Iterator to List

Tags: java, list, iterator

Given `Iterator<Element>`, how can we conveniently convert that `Iterator` to a `List<Element>`, so that we can use `List`'s operations on it such as `get(index)`, `add(element)`, etc.

Answer (score 401, accepted):

Better use a library like [Guava](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#newArrayList-java.util.Iterator-):

```
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

Iterator<Element> myIterator = ... //some iterator
List<Element> myList = Lists.newArrayList(myIterator);
```

Another Guava example:

```
ImmutableList.copyOf(myIterator);
```

or [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/):

```
import org.apache.commons.collections.IteratorUtils;

Iterator<Element> myIterator = ...//some iterator

List<Element> myList = IteratorUtils.toList(myIterator);
```

Comment: I don't get it. In what way is the ArrayList returned by, say, Guava any better than a normal ArrayList? Do they do it in a more efficient way? Even if it is more efficient is it really worth adding an extra dependency (and more complexity) to your project?

Comment: @CorayThan less code + tested methods. Though I agree with you I would not add an extra dependency just to use that method. But then again, most of my (large) projects use either Guava or Apache Commons...

Comment: @CorayThan Divide and conquer my friend. Why write a method that is already provided by a library and is tested? We are using a lot of Apache Commons and Guava, they are just awesome and help you save time and money.

Comment: Agree with Renaud and Stephan.  Also, if you're using a build tool it's the easiest thing in the world to include these libraries... ALSO... if you really don't want to include them you can go to the source of Apache/Guava code and copy what they've done there: FAR better than wasting your time reinventing the hundreds of beautifully engineered and tested wheels which are already out there.

Answer (score 287):

In Java 8, you can use the new `forEachRemaining` method that's been added to the `Iterator` interface:

```
List<Element> list = new ArrayList<>();
iterator.forEachRemaining(list::add);
```

Comment: what means `::`? what name has it? seems a direct reference to list.add(); and seems also some java8 new thing; and thanks! :)

Comment: @AquariusPower The `::` syntax is new in Java 8, and it refers to a "method reference," which is a shorthand form of a lambda. See here for further info: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html

Comment: where is `iterator` coming from? it is an unresolved symbol

Comment: @javadba The original question was about how to convert an iterator that you already have into a new ArrayList. For purposes of this example, the iterator you already have is assumed to be called `iterator`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it's the shortest and do not depend on 3rd party libraries

Answer (score 73):

You can copy an iterator to a new list like this:

```
Iterator<String> iter = list.iterator();
List<String> copy = new ArrayList<String>();
while (iter.hasNext())
    copy.add(iter.next());
```

That's assuming that the list contains strings. There really isn't a faster way to recreate a list from an iterator, you're stuck with traversing it by hand and copying each element to a new list of the appropriate type.

**EDIT :**

Here's a generic method for copying an iterator to a new list in a type-safe way:

```
public static <T> List<T> copyIterator(Iterator<T> iter) {
    List<T> copy = new ArrayList<T>();
    while (iter.hasNext())
        copy.add(iter.next());
    return copy;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");
Iterator<String> iter = list.iterator();
List<String> copy = copyIterator(iter);
System.out.println(copy);
> [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Wouldn't `Iterator<? extends T> it` be more flexible in your method declaration?

Answer (score 31):

Note there is a difference between [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) and [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).

If you have an **`Iterable`**, then with Java 8 you can use this solution:

```
Iterable<Element> iterable = createIterable();
List<Element> array = StreamSupport
    .stream(iterable.spliterator(), false)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As I know `Collectors.toList()` creates `ArrayList` instance.

Actually in my opinion, it also looks good in one line.
For example if you need to return `List<Element>` from some method:

```
return StreamSupport.stream(iter.spliterator(), false).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: The question is about Iterator<Element> as a starting point, not Iterable<Element>.

Comment: agree with the above comment. super confusing that you named your `Iterable` `iterator`. They are *completely* different.

Comment: In Java 8 you can easily convert an `Iterator` back to a **single use** `Iterable` by using `() -> iterator`. This can be useful in situations like this, but let me stress the important thing again: You can use this method only if a **single use** `Iterable` is acceptable. Calling `iterable.iterator()` more than once will yield unexpected results. The above answer then becomes `Iterator<Element> iterator = createIterator();` `List<Element> array = StreamSupport.stream(((Iterable<Element>) () -> iterable).spliterator(), false).collect(toList());`

Answer (score 24):

You can also use [`IteratorUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/IteratorUtils.html) from Apache [commons-collections](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/), although it doesn't support generics:

```
List list = IteratorUtils.toList(iterator);
```

Comment: It also has 2 toArray Method and 1 accepts a type :http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/IteratorUtils.html#toArray(java.util.Iterator, java.lang.Class)

Answer (score 10):

Pretty concise solution with plain Java 8 using [`java.util.stream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html):

```
public static <T> ArrayList<T> toArrayList(final Iterator<T> iterator) {
    return StreamSupport
        .stream(
            Spliterators
                .spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator, Spliterator.ORDERED), false)
        .collect(
                Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)
    );
}
```

Comment: Is there a more compact way to write this using stream api? It seems not simpler than the normal while loop way.

Comment: I would not call that solution "concise".

Comment: @Sergio That's why I wrote "pretty". However, it doesn't need local variables and only one semicolon. You may shorten it with static imports.

Comment: I'd say `iterator.forEachRemaining( list::add )`, also new in Java 8, is a lot more concise. Pushing the list variable into `Collector` does not improve readibility in this case, since it has to be supported by a `Stream` and a `Spliterator`.

Comment: @Sergio It's not short, but it's a single expression, which makes a huge difference.

Answer (score 8):

**Without external dependency**, here's a one-liner using Streams and java 16 toList().

Given an `Iterator<?> iterator`:

```
List<?> list = StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator, 0), false).toList();
```

Comment: one can set parallel to 'true' in order to make list faser.

Answer (score 6):

```
List result = new ArrayList();
while (i.hasNext()){
    result.add(i.next());
}
```

Comment: @LuggiMendoza: Stack Overflow is not meant to be a place where you can just cut and paste and solve your problem. It is meant to be informative. This is a perfectly informative answer and any reasonable person should be able to put it together that the i was an iterator. 

From the sounds of it, you put almost no effort into trying to understand what was going on.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`StickyList`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.cactoos/cactoos/0.20.2/org/cactoos/list/StickyList.html) from [Cactoos](http://www.cactoos.org):

```
List<String> list = new StickyList<>(iterable);
```

Disclaimer: I'm one of the developers.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. `Iterable` != `Iterator`

Comment: Great, now you probably need to generate JavaDoc for the new version and update the link. :)

Answer (score 1):

I just want to point out a seemingly obvious solution that **will NOT** work:

```
List list = Stream.generate(iterator::next)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

That's because [`Stream#generate(Supplier<T>)`](//docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#generate-java.util.function.Supplier-) can create only infinite streams, it doesn't expect its argument to throw [`NoSuchElementException`](//docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html) (that's what [`Iterator#next()`](//docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next--) will do in the end).

[The xehpuk's answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/23997880) should be used instead if the Iterator→Stream→List way is your choice.

Answer (score 0):

use google [guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) !

```
Iterable<String> fieldsIterable = ...
List<String> fields = Lists.newArrayList(fieldsIterable);
```

++

Comment: Iterator (not Iterable) to ArrayList

Answer (score -3):

Here in this case if you want the fastest way possible then `for loop` is better.

The iterator over a sample size of `10,000 runs` takes `40 ms` where as for loop takes `2 ms`

```
        ArrayList<String> alist = new ArrayList<String>();  
        long start, end;  

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {  
            alist.add(String.valueOf(i));  
        }  

        ListIterator<String> it = alist.listIterator();      

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();  
        while (it.hasNext()) {  
            String s = it.next();  
        }  
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();  

        System.out.println("Iterator start: " + start + ", end: " + end + ", delta: "  
            + (end - start));  
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();  
        int ixx = 0;  
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {  
            String s = alist.get(i);  
        }  

        System.out.println(ixx);  
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();  
        System.out.println("for loop start: " + start + ", end: " + end + ", delta: "  
            + (end - start));
```

That's assuming that the list contains strings.

Comment: Surely using a `for` loop and accessing a list's elements with `get(i)` is faster than using an iterator... but that's not what the OP was asking, he specifically mentioned that an _iterator_ is given as input.

Comment: @Oscar i am sorry.Should i delete my answer?

Comment: That's your call. I wouldn't delete it yet, it might be informative. I only delete my answers when people start to downvote them :)

Comment: I think @ÓscarLópez is right ... this may not be the required answer, but it contains useful information for readers (like myself :P).

Comment: You have a bug in your answer.  In the `get(int)` loop you are only looking at 100k of the 1m entries.  If you change that loop to be `it.size()` you will see that these 2 methods are close to the same speed.  In general these sorts of java speed tests provide limited real life performance information and should be looked at skeptically.