# how can I iterate over a list of objects in sightly?

Tags: adobe, aem, sightly

I have created a Java class method `getmyPages()` which returns `iterator<Page>`.
Now in HTML page I am able to instantiate the class and access other properties of this class.

However I want to iterate over this iterator the way `currentPage.listChildren` works.....

Since `currentPage.listChildren` returns `iterator<Page>`
I am also returning same.

However I am not able to ...... the HTML tag in which I am printing this comes out empty.

Comment: Can you post your sightly code as well, this would help understand your problem. Though it could be that only lists are alowed, I never tried it with an iterator. You can convert an Iterator to a List with the answers from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10117026/convert-iterator-to-arraylist

Answer (score 6):

You can use `data-sly-list` attribute to loop over an iterator. Here's an excerpt from [Feike Visser's](http://experiencedelivers.adobe.com/cemblog/en/experiencedelivers.html?blog=author&author=Feike%20Visser) Sightly tutorials :

```
<ul data-sly-list.child="${currentPage.listChildren}">
  <li>${child.title}</li>
</ul>
```

`data-sly-unwrap` attribute can be used to prevent enclosing tag of the loop from being part of the final mark up

```
<ul data-sly-list.child="${currentPage.listChildren}" data-sly-unwrap>
  <li>${child.title}</li>
</ul>
```

Link to the tutorials : [http://blogs.adobe.com/experiencedelivers/experience-management/sightly-intro-part-1](http://blogs.adobe.com/experiencedelivers/experience-management/sightly-intro-part-1/)

Documentation of `data-sly-list` : [link](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/sightly.html#list)

Answer (score -1):

java class
public class TabControl extends WCMUse {

```
@Override
public void activate() throws Exception {
    // nothing to be done here in this case
}

  public Iterator<Map<String, Object>> getTabTitles(){

      final I18n i18n = new I18n(getRequest());
      List<Map<String, Object>> infos = new LinkedList<Map<String,Object>>();
      String[] tabTitles = getProperties().get("tabs", String[].class);
   if (tabTitles == null || tabTitles.length == 0) {
         tabTitles = new String[1];
         tabTitles[0] = i18n.get("Tab One from sightly");
         Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
         map.put("tabTitle",  tabTitles[0]);
         infos.add(map);
   }else if(tabTitles.length > 0){
       for (String tab : tabTitles) {
           Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
           map.put("tabTitle",  tab);
           infos.add(map);   
    }
   }
   return  infos.iterator();
}



 }
```

Comment: <header class="tabctrl-header"  data-sly-use.topnav2="apps.dhl.components.content.tabctrl.TabControl">
   <ul   data-sly-list.tab1="${topnav2.getTabTitles}">
          <li><a href="#${tab1List.index}">  ${tab1.tabTitle}</a></li>
            
   </ul>
</header>

Answer (score -1):

In my Java code I'm returning a List then using Sightly

Java Class

```
public class ListFilesUse extends WCMUsePojo{

private String name;

private List<TrFile> files = new ArrayList<TrFile>();
```

Sightly

```
<div data-sly-use.test="apps.ecolorado.components.sharedcontent.ListFilesUse">
    ${test.name}
    <ul data-sly-list.child="${test.files}">
        <li>${child.fileName}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And this is working in progress code.