# Iterable - Move to specified position

Tags: java, iterator

- I need an iterable data structure that provides the possibilities of
  the standard `Iterator<>` interface (`next()`, `hasNext()`, etc.).
- Additionally it should be possible to reposition the iterator at a
  certain position.

---

Is there any class that already provides the mentioned possibilities?

---

Otherwise I would implement something like the following:

```
public class PositionableIterator<E> implements Iterator<E> {

  private final List<E> delegate;
  private Iterator<E> iterator;

  public PositionableIterator(List<E> delegate) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
    this.iterator = delegate.iterator();
  }

  public void moveTo(int index) {
    this.iterator = delegate.listIterator(index);
  }

  public void moveTo(E element) {
    this.iterator = delegate.listIterator(delegate.indexOf(element));
  }

  @Override
  public boolean hasNext() {
    return iterator.hasNext();
  }

  @Override
  public E next() {
    return iterator.next();
  }
}
```

Do you see any drawbacks using this approach?

Comment: One drawback is that if the ``List`` does not have random access (sequential access, linked list), then it is parsed till the index-th object for every call to ``moveTo``. This is expensive for a large List. ``moveTo(E element)`` is even more costly.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest just convert iterator to list and use its functionality. Because that way it is easier to understand and maintain. There is example of converting [Convert Iterator to ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10117026/convert-iterator-to-arraylist)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same by doing the following :

```
Iterator<String> iterator = input.iterator();
for (; index > 0; --index) {
      iterator.next();       // move the iterator to index
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Google guavas [Iterables](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/27.1-jre/api/docs/) methods to get an item from a specific position from an Iterable.

```
Iterator<Something> iterator = repo.GetMyIterator();

Something atPos5 = Iterables.get(iterator, 5);
```