# Kotlin iterator to list?

Tags: kotlin

I have an iterator of strings from [fieldNames](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#fieldNames%28%29) of `JsonNode`:

```
val mm = ... //JsonNode
val xs = mm.fieldNames()
```

I want to loop over the fields while keeping count, something like:

```
when mm.size() {
  1 -> myFunction1(xs[0])
  2 -> myFunction2(xs[0], xs[1])
  3 -> myFunction3(xs[0], xs[1], xs[2])
  else -> print("invalid")
}
```

Obviously the above code does not work as `xs` the Iterator cannot be indexed like so. I tried to see if I can convert the iterator to list by `mm.toList()` but that does not exist.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10117026/convert-iterator-to-arraylist tells you how to convert an iterator into a list in Java. It's trivial to do the same in Kotlin.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to convert iterator to `Sequence` first and then to `List`:

```
listOf(1,2,3).iterator().asSequence().toList()
```

result:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I used it as json.keys().iterator().asSequence().toList()

Comment: `asSequence` is not required, it's redundant

Comment: @xenoterracide are you sure about that? Just checked with Kotlin 1.7, skipping `asSequence` [doesn't work](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS43LjEwIiwiY29kZSI6ImZ1biBtYWluKCkge1xuXHRsaXN0T2YoMSwgMiwgMykuaXRlcmF0b3IoKS50b0xpc3QoKVxufSIsInBsYXRmb3JtIjoiamF2YSIsImFyZ3MiOiIifQ==)

Answer (score 7):

You can turn an `Iterator` into an `Iterable` using `Iterable { iterator }` on which you can then call `toList()`:

```
Iterable { listOf(1,2,3).iterator() }.toList() // [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 4):

I would skip the conversion to sequence, because it is only a few lines of code.

```
fun <T> Iterator<T>.toList(): List<T> =
    ArrayList<T>().apply {
        while (hasNext())
            this += next()
    }
```

---

Update:

Please keep in mind though, that appending to an `ArrayList` is not that performant, so for longer lists, you are better off with the following, or with the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46108166/4420543):

```kotlin
    fun <T> Iterator<T>.toList(): List<T> =
        LinkedList<T>().apply {
            while (hasNext())
                this += next()
        }.toMutableList()
```

Comment: `Sequence.toList()` appends items to an `ArrayList` internally, so it must be performant. Which makes sense since each `LinkedList.add` requires an allocation while `ArrayList.add` reallocates the backing array with spare capacity for following elements.