# Return iterators item value for matching condition

Tags: kotlin

I'm parsing excel file and I'm trying to find an index for "IP" column.
The code below will actually give me the index, but return value type for that 'let' is Any.

Is there a prettier way to get data from iterator if the data matches with if statement?

```
val ipColumn = headerRow.cellIterator().let {
    it.forEach { cell ->  
        if ("IP" == formater.formatCellValue(cell))
            return@let cell.columnIndex 
    }
}
```

Comment: headerRow is of what type?

Comment: it is a Row from package org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel

Comment: please check out my edited answer, I figured out a neater way I guess :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're using Apache POI library, where `cellIterator` is a method returning an `Iterator<Cell>`. In such a case, you could do something like this:

```
val ipColumn: Int? = headerRow.cellIterator()
    .asSequence()
    .firstOrNull {
        "IP" == formatter.formatCellValue(it)
    }
    ?.columnIndex
```

Please note I didn't test the code, so it might even contain compilation issues, but I hope it gives you a hint

Answer (score 1):

### Using `List` or `Sequence`

Your best bet would be [converting the iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46107706/kotlin-iterator-to-list) to `Sequence`, where you can call the `find()` method.

```
val index = headerRow
    .asSequence() //To sequence
    .find { "IP" == formater.formatCellValue(it) }
```

### Using `Iterator`

If for some kind of reason you can't use `List` I don't really think there is a prettier way (of course there always can be). But if your main problem is that you get a type of `Any` from your `let` construction you can always just [cast](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html) the found index with `as Int` or if you are not sure that the index will be of type `Int`, use `as? Int`, which will return [nullable value](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html) of Int:

```
val ipColumn = headerRow.cellIterator().let {
it.forEach { cell ->  
    if ("IP" == formater.formatCellValue(cell))
        return@let cell.columnIndex 
    }
} as Int //This returns `Int`
```

### Using extensions

If you still don't like any of those 2 options. Or if you want to use the code in more places. You can create yourself an [extension function/method](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html):

```
fun Row.find(predicate: (Cell) -> Boolean): Cell? 
    = cellIterator().asSequence().find(predicate) //Put this code anywhere is your code...
```

After you put these lines anywhere in your code, you can simply call:

```
val index = headerRow
    .find { "IP" == formater.formatCellValue(it) }?
    .columnIndex //This returns optional Int
```

*Please note, that I did not compile any of these examples, I do not have the necessary library for that!*

Comment: Why convert to `List`? This is just unnecessary extra work.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov My bad, I edited my answer, brain freeze I guess  Thank you though for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

Not from an `Iterator` directly, but it can be converted to a [`Sequence`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/-sequence/index.html). Of course, usually you'll have an `Iterable` and be able to call `find` and so on directly, maybe in this case too depending on type of `headerRow`:

```
headerRow.cellIterator().asSequence().
    find { cell -> "IP" == formater.formatCellValue(cell) }?.
    columnIndex
```

`?.` in the end handles the case where `find` returned `null` because there's no suitable column.