# Programmatically arranging contents in aem 6.4

Tags: java, adobe, aem, aem-6

everyone. I'm new in working with `aem`. I'm using `aem 6.4`. My task is to programmatically sort the order of the contents of a `cq:project` in `aem` depending on the content of a JSON file.
The content of the JSON file should be set as the initial child instead of the children sorted by their creation date.

This is the current structure of my `cq:page`. If the child2 is the one indicated in the JSON file, it should be the first one to be displayed. The content of the JSON file is just the name of one child so even though there are 10 children, the content of the JSON file should always be the first one in the list.

[image]

I've spent hours researching on how I can implement this although I still can't find any solution. Any insights on how should I create this? Thanks!

Comment: I’m having a hard time following your question. What is the JSON file? And how does it relate to the node structure? Can you please provide the node structure before ordering and after ordering with an example JSON so we can help further?

Comment: The JSON file contains the configuration which should be the default of the dropdown list that I'm creating. Currently, the dropdown list gets the order of the children of the 'parent-proj' as indicated in the image. If the json file contains 'child2', it should be the first child of parent-proj.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you want a way to order a named child of a `cq:Page` to be first in the list.

> This is possible because cq:Page is an [`orderable`](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/spec/jcr/2.0/23_Orderable_Child_Nodes.html) node. This would not be possible otherwise. you chan check any nodetype in CRX Explorer.

I think adding the bit about JSON complicates the question. You just need a simple method such as the following:

```
private void orderAsFirstChild(String childName, Node parentNode) throws RepositoryException {
    if (parentNode.hasNode(childName)) {

      // find current first child name
      String firstChildName = Optional.ofNullable(parentNode.getNodes())
          .map(NodeIterator::nextNode)
          .map(node -> {
            try {
              node.getName();
            } catch (RepositoryException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return (String) null;
          }) //
          .orElse(null);
      parentNode.orderBefore(childName, firstChildName);
    }
  }
```

You should probably clean this up a little, but this is the general idea using [`Node#orderBefore`](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/spec/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/Node.html#orderBefore(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: I just tweaked this a little and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This may helps -

1. Get the children from the parent node.(you will get 'iterator' convert it to list here-[Convert Iterator to ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10117026/convert-iterator-to-arraylist))
2. Delete all child nodes now. And keep the back up of above list.
   iterate through the list , identify the node which you want place first(by title or some other property) add that to a separate set(LinkedHashSet- to maintain order).
3. Now add the remaining items/nodes in the same order after your specific node in the above set.(you may need to iterate through again)
4. Now this Set has nodes/Resources in the order which you want, iterate , create nodes and save your changes.